# IPFS RPC API : ipfs routing findprovs provides an unreadable response

Tags: rpc, ipfs

I have a fresh install of IPFS daemon on my computer :

```
ipfs init
ipfs daemon
```

When running the following command, the output seems correct:

> $ ipfs routing findprovs QmUZzfuaCcPSXgADUnkF1GKBsDRUxxxxxxxxx
> 12D3KooWLJBTtGHSbeqHSEkAo4jTni1PBrtRktV2a85yKxxxxxx

When requesting the RPC API as follows (should give the same input as CLI):

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/routing/findprovs?arg=QmUZzfuaCcPSXgADUnkF1GKBsDRUxxxxxxxxx"
```

The response I get contains multiple JSON objects (100+) separated by \n

```
{"Extra":"","ID":"12D3KooWAH9RHKrbpS1nZC7Wos91y8dD4HwN5Wq2JmHjxxxxxxx","Responses":null,"Type":7}
{"Extra":"","ID":"12D3KooWHWEKWG6Mh4ZgoCmxhP2uhyyVdBJGt388LMLXQQxxxxxx","Responses":null,"Type":0}
....
```

How can I get the same result as the CLI using the RPC API ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution (that is really not ideal) after further investigation and confirmation from [this github post](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/issues/2868)

Turns out the returned providers with `Type=4` are the ones identified by the CLI. Here is a ruby example to extract those from the response (after treating the response as plain text and not Json) :

```rb
response.body.each_line
             .map{     |line|           JSON.parse(line) }
             .filter{  |parsed_line|    parsed_line['Type'] == 4 }
             .collect{ |parsed_line|    parsed_line['Responses'] }
             .map{     |responses|      responses[0] }
             .map{     |first_response| first_response['ID'] }

# ["QmQzqxhK82kAmKvARFZSkUVS6fo9sySaiogAnx5Enxxxx",
# "12D3KooWFzZYEChh6Dsy4jHyTopK42oRrk41WVfnpMG5rxxxxxx",
```